# Remove punctuation from string

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a string and I need to remove these symbols:  `-- + [ ] { } ( ) \ /`

For example:

```
    String clean = "This \ is / an example. This -- is + an [(example)].";

    clean = clean.replaceAll("[/[()/]]", "");
    clean = clean.replaceAll("/-/-", "");

    clean = clean.replaceAll("\\/","");
    clean = clean.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");
    clean = clean.replaceAll("\\+", "");

    return clean.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ").trim();
```

My output should be:  `This is an example. This is an example.`

My code does not remove everything I need and also I would like to know if there is a shorter way to do this.

--

Just some particularities I should mention: `-` should be removed only if there are two together. 
`/` should be replaced by a whitespace. I'm going to try to adapt your solutions here. Thanks.

Comment: `/` is not an escape character, unless I'm greatly mistaken.

Comment: This is what I have done until now. It's not right. I'm trying to get it right with your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply call the String.replaceAll method and specify that those characters must be replaced by the empty String:

```
clean = clean.replaceAll("(?:--|[\\[\\]{}()+/\\\\])", "");
```

But if you need to do this many times, it's worth creating a Pattern object so that the regex does not have to be compiled repeatedly:

```
private static final Pattern UNWANTED_SYMBOLS =
        Pattern.compile("(?:--|[\\[\\]{}()+/\\\\])");
```

Now you can use this to create a Matcher object and use that to do the replacement:

```
Matcher unwantedMatcher = UNWANTED_SYMBOLS.matcher(clean);
clean = unwantedMatcher.replaceAll("");
```

This should be more efficient if you need to use the replacement in a loop which runs more than a few times.

Comment: Is there a way to tell this pattern instead of replace `-` by an empty string, only remove it if there is two of them together `--` ?

Comment: I've edited the regex pattern so that it should match a double-hyphen and not a single hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

One, you do not escape using `/`, you do it using `\`.

Two, if you need to use `\`, you have to double escape it to get it into the regular expression.

Three, you can combine all the expressions into one regex.

Four, you can chain calls to `replaceAll()`.

```
public class Replace { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String clean = "This \\ is / an example. This -- is + an [(example)].";

        clean = clean.replaceAll("[\\[()\\]{}+\\\\\\/-]", "").replaceAll(" +", " ");
        System.out.println(clean.trim());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is an example. This is an example.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove everything in one fell swoop. Just put everything in a character class (`[]`).

```
[\[\]+{}()\\/-]
```

As in:

```
clean = clean.replaceAll("[\\[\\]+{}()\\\\/-]", "");
```

Comment: The Java regex engine doesn't seem to like `[][...]` - although the empty character group is invalid so the close bracket is ignored - the open bracket makes it angry...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks, I guess I'll have to be on the safe side...

Comment: Ok. Just some particularities. - should be removed only if there are two together. And / should be replaced by a whitespace. I'm going to try to adapt your solutions here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
String clean = "This \\ is / an example. This -- is + an [(example)].";

return clean.replaceAll("[(--)+\\[\\]{}()\\\\/]", "").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/` by `\\` when escaping.

```
String clean = "This \\ is / an example. This -- is + an [(example)]."; // Had to change \ to \\

clean = clean.replaceAll("[\\[()\\]]", "");
clean = clean.replaceAll("\\-\\-", "");

clean = clean.replaceAll("\\/","");
clean = clean.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");
clean = clean.replaceAll("\\+", "");
```

Comment: That is a very inefficent way of replacing a fixed set of characters. A single regex can represent all of the characters in one go.

Comment: Indeed. Just wanted to point out that the problem was the escape character.

Comment: But the forward slash is not a special character in regex, so you don't need to escape it.